# permission denied access php5 folder

Tags: 14.04, php

I wanted to access files php5 folder on \var\lib\php5, but I got permission denied.
I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Is it Ubuntu lock the permission for the folder and need root access?
Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

Iccsi

Comment: Could you post which command you did and `namei -mo /var/lib/php5` command output?

Comment: myuser@mymachine:/var/lib$ cd php5
myuser@mymachine:/var/lib/php5$ ls
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied

Comment: myuser@mymachine:/var/lib/php5$ namei -mo /var/lib/php5
f: /var/lib/php5
 drwxr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root var
 drwxr-xr-x root root lib
 drwx-wx-wt root root php5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, command `namei -mo /var/lib/php5` output is:

```
     drwxr-xr-x root root / 
     drwxr-xr-x root root var 
     drwxr-xr-x root root lib 
     drwx-wx-wt root root php5
```

`php5` folder permission `drwx-wx-wt` means:

- `drwx` this is a directory and the owner (root) has read, write and execute permission
- `-wx`  users in root group have write and execute permission, they can't read
- `-wt`  other users have write and execute permission, but can't read. `t` also tell that this folder can be removed only by the owner

If you want to read this folder you need `root` privilege, so try this command:

```
     sudo ls /var/lib/php5
```

According to [sudo manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html):

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or
>   another user, as specified by the security policy.

Be careful to use `sudo` command, because gaining root permissions, you can do anything and if you mess up, you can compromise the system.